# sql to remove rows that match in content to a more complete row

Tags: sql

I'm looking for sql to remove rows that match in content to a more complete row.  I've been stuck on this one for days. only one of the columns is not nullable (col_c).

```
**sample input data**
```

```
col_a   col_b    col_c     col_d  
-----------------------------------
cat              duck      giraffe       
cat              duck         
                 duck      giraffe
                 dog       wolf
cat              dog       wolf   
elk              zebra 
        giraffe  duck
        leopard  lion      puma
        wolf     lion
```

**expected results**

```
col_a   col_b    col_c     col_d  
------------------------------------
cat              duck      giraffe       
cat              dog       wolf   
elk              zebra 
        giraffe  duck
        leopard  lion      puma
        wolf     lion
```

**attempted code**

```
select animal.*
from animal
where not exists (select 1
              from animal as animal2
              where animal2.col_c = animal.col_c
              and (animal.col_a is null or animal2.col_a = animal.col_a)  
              and (animal.col_b is null or animal2.col_b = animal.col_b)  
              and (animal.col_d is null or animal2.col_d = animal.col_d)
               and not (
                        ((animal.col_a = animal2.col_a) or (animal.col_a is null and animal2.col_a is null))
                        ((animal.col_b = animal2.col_b) or (animal.col_b is null and animal2.col_b is null))
                        ((animal.col_d = animal2.col_d) or (animal.col_d is null and animal2.col_d is null))
                        )  


)
```

Comment: I forgot to add that the attempted code gave all input records. I used the "not" part of the query to eliminate matches against the same record

Comment: Forgive me for saying so, but this looks like really poor table/database design.  It would help for you to show the `CREATE TABLE` statement, so that we may see things like what is the primary key for this table.  I see many possible edge cases in your data which you may not have even thought about.

Comment: Hi Tim, this is output given to me in excel that I put into a database. I'll try to get the original table DDL and the query that was used in the excel extract. I changed the "exists" to "not exists"

Answer (score 1):

Below query should work:

```
select * from animal a where  exists (select 1 from animal other where 
                                                        (other.col_a = a.col_a or a.col_a is null)
                                                        and (other.col_b = a.col_b or a.col_b is null)
                                                        and (other.col_c = a.col_c or a.col_c is null)
                                                        and (other.col_d = a.col_d or a.col_d is null)
                                                        and other.ID <> a.ID)
```

Comment: Yay it worked. My Hero! This solution requires a new field called "ID" though. It would be interesting to see a solution without the "ID" field especially for ms-access

Comment: It is always beneficial to have an ID column. In this query i use ID column to be sure that i compare my record with other records but not with itself. But if you don't have a ID column for some reason, you can use this statement "and (other.col_a != a.col_a or other.col_b != a.col_b or other.col_c != a.col_c or other.col_d != a.col_d )" for the same purpose, instead of this " and other.ID <> a.ID"

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not specify if your statement should be performant. But if I were you, I would store your data into a temporary table, and then loop through the data. Something like this:

> select animal.*, 0 AS [Done] into #animal from animal

Then order this set by the most complete record (all props filled). Then loop through this set and delete less complete records from this set.

In the end just simply run:

> select * from #animal